# Visual Studio Code Syntax Highlighting shows errors but compiles

Tags: c++, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting, glut

Visual Studio Code highlights all my glut functions as undefined, but compiles flawlessly. How can I get rid of the red underlining, without deactivating the syntax highlighting?

[image: highlighting errors]

Includes of `main.h`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string>
```

I added all paths I could think of to the include path and browse path section in the `c_cpp_properties.json` file.

```
{
"name": "Linux",
"includePath": [
    "/usr/include",
    "/usr/include/GL",
    "/usr/local/include",
    "${workspaceRoot}",
    "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/5",
    "/usr/include/c++/5",
    "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu"
],
"defines": [],
"intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64",
"browse": {
    "path": [
        "/usr/include",
        "/usr/include/GL",
        "/usr/local/include",
        "${workspaceRoot}",
        "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/5",
        "/usr/include/c++/5",
        "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu"
    ],
    "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
    "databaseFilename": ""
    }
}
```

I use Visual Studio Code 1.18 on Ubuntu 16.04 and my build command is:

`g++ -g main.cpp -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lGL -lglut -lGLEW -lGLU`

Any ideas?

Comment: please don't put code as image. copy the relevant part of `c_cpp_properties.json` and paste here

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc When you said "code", I initially thought you were complaining about the source code image (which would be unreasonable - the image is to show the error highlighting).  I agree that the json configuration should be displayed as text, not an imaged (but I don't think it is really "code").

Comment: Could this be an issue of flushing the IDE's cache? I find it often changes things.

Comment: Aren't `#include <GL/gl.h>` and the likes also needed?

Comment: @Carlos I do not know how to do this. I cleared the editor history - did not help.

Comment: @Bob__ Unfortunately that  does not change a thing.

Comment: What's in main.h? Are there any other includes out of sight of your screen shot. Would be good if you could post the code as well.

Comment: Do you have the same error switching to `"C_Cpp.intelliSenseMode": "Tag Parser"`?

Comment: @Bob__ It works! Thanks man.

Comment: Well, that's only a workaround. You should really try to find out the needed include path. I was bugged by another intellisense issue which force me to add `"defines": [ "__SIZE_TYPE__=unsigned long long int" ],`, because it reported `size_t` as undefined or unsigned long, causing all sort of weird highlighted problems.

Answer (score 2):

Setting the `"C_Cpp.intelliSenseMode": "Tag Parser"` in the `settings.json` does the trick. Thanks a lot @Bob__

Comment: This was the solution that finally worked for me