# how to set "C_Cpp.intelliSenseMode": "Tag Parser" in visual studio code

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

Basd on this question in SO : [Visual Studio Code Syntax Highlighting shows errors but compiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47429752/visual-studio-code-syntax-highlighting-shows-errors-but-compiles)

I want to set "C_Cpp.intelliSenseMode": "Tag Parser" in setting.json,

But I am not able to set it.

[image]

as when add it to setting.json, I am getting the following error:

```
Unknown configuration setting
```

I am using the folloing tools:

- Ubuntu 18.04
- Visual studio 1.23.1
- C/.C++ extension 0.17

How can I add this setting?

for your inform, I have similar problem as explained the the original question, I am getting error on editor but the application compiled correctly.

Comment: [probably related](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/blob/master/Documentation/LanguageServer/FAQ.md#why-do-i-see-red-squiggles-under-standard-library-types)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the correct setting to use in *settings.json* is "C_Cpp.intelliSense**Engine**": "Tag Parser"

The *intelliSenseMode* setting is used in *c_cpp_properties.json* in order to have a working autocomplete with standard libraries.

Comment: I tried a lot of other suggestions, but putting "C_Cpp.intelliSenseEngine": "Tag Parser" in *settings.json* is what fixed the annoying 'include' squiggles for me.